# Docker-compose custom .env file unexpected behaviour

Tags: bash, docker, shell, docker-compose, environment-variables

## Example

Consider this example docker-compose file with custom .env file:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  service_example:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
      args:
        AAA: ${AAA}
    command: python3 src/service/run.py
    env_file:
      - custom_env.env
```

`custom_env.env`:

```sh
AAA=qqq
```

When I run `docker-compose config` I get the following output:

```
WARNING: The AAA variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
services:
  service_example:
    build:
      args:
        AAA: ''   <----------------------------- ??????
      context: /Users/examples
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: python3 src/service/run.py
    environment:
      AAA: qqq
version: '3'
```

## Question

Why `AAA` is unset in `build` section?
What should I do to set it properly (to the value provided from custom file: `AAA=qqq`)?

I've also noticed that if I change the env file name to the [default setting](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file) `mv custom_env.env .env` and remove `env_file` section from `docker-compose.yml` - everything will be just fine:

```yaml
services:
  service_example:
    build:
      args:
        AAA: qqq
      context: /Users/examples
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: python3 src/service/run.py
version: '3'
```

Comment: @TelinovDmitri so how should it look like?

Comment: env_file is used when running the particular container, not for compose and potential expansion. Compose is always using the .env or variables in the current shell. If you want to use a custom env file you need to use the --env-file flag on compose `docker compose --env-file .customenv config`.

Comment: expansion works in a compose file but only if there is something to expand. The reason you cannot provide the env file inside the compose file is that compose also reads the location of the compose file itself from the .env. If you set COMPOSE_FILE there, for example.-

Comment: env_file is also the wrong choice if you indent to use those during build time. It would never work, not even with plain docker. In fact you cannot provide a env file on the docker build command.

Comment: Yes, but default name `.env` works perfectly during build time. That's kinda strange.

Comment: @IvanVinogradov, because compose is reading .env to apply the variable to the compose config. That is different from an env file you use to run a container. Like I said, you need to use the --env-file flag on the compose commmand to use a custom file. Then it will work as you expect. The issue is that you are mixing 2 different things together, thinking they are the same, while they are not.

Comment: _default name .env works perfectly during build time_ - Do you have a separate shell extension like `dotenv` / `direnv` that loads any file named `.env` into the current environment's variables? That would be completely separate from Docker and explains why it _may work_

Comment: No, I have no separate extensions. You can try my example by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

#### Quick Answer

> `docker-compose --env-file custom_env.env config`

---

### Answers Explanation

##### Question-1: Why AAA is unset in build section?

Because the env file specified in `env_file` property `custom_env.env` is specific for the Container only, i.e. those variables are to be passed to container while running not during image build.

---

##### Question-2: What should I do to set it properly (to the value provided from custom file: AAA=qqq)?

To provide environment variables for build step in `docker-compose` file using custom env file, we need to specify the custom file path. Like

Syntax: `docker-compose --env-file FILE_PATH config`

Example: `docker-compose --env-file custom_env.env config`

---

##### Question-3: How `.env` works?

Because that is the default file for which docker-compose looks for.

---

### Summary

So, In `docker-compose` for current scenario we can consider 2 stages for specifying `env`

1. Build Stage(Image)
2. Running Stage(Container)

- **For Build stage** - we can use `.env` default file or we can use `--env-file` option to specify custom env file
- **For Running Stage** - we can specify environment variables using `environment:` property or we can use `env_file:` property to specify a env file

---

### References

- https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/
- https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/
- https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#env_file
- https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment

---